# Accessing ViewData Model in PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, viewdata

I pass data to partial view like this.

```
@foreach (var order in Model.Orders)
{
    @Html.Partial("_GridCellsPartial", null, new ViewDataDictionary(new  ViewDataDictionary() { { "order", order } }) { Model = Model })
}
```

Now is there a way to access order in the partialView. Order has also got a list of items within it. So am I able to grab order form the viewdatadictionary somehow and then get at the list items within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the "order" instance as a Model object directly to the "Partial" method and use it inside the "_GridCellsPartial" PartialView in the following manner:

Render:

```
@foreach (var order in Model.Orders)
{
    @*@Html.Partial("_GridCellsPartial", null, new ViewDataDictionary(new  ViewDataDictionary() { { "order", order } }) { Model = Model })*@

    @Html.Partial("_GridCellsPartial", order)
}
```

_GridCellsPartial:

```
@model OrderTypeClassNameHere

<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    @*Model = Order Instance*@
    <li>@item</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your `ViewData` data like you'd do in a normal dictionary:

```
@ViewData["yourkey"]
```